# App Script to move a row of data from one Google sheet to a different one (different sheet id's) based on a cell entry

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I'm currently trying to adjust a script I found that copies the contents of a row from one tab of a google sheet, pastes it into the next descending empty row in a different tab and then deletes the original row.

```
function onEdit() {

  var sheetNameToWatch = "Original_Sheet";

  var columnNumberToWatch = 3;
  var valueToWatch = "ValueToLookFor";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Target_Sheet";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();


  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
}
```

What I want to do from here is be able to run the same script but with the target sheet to be a sheet located on a completely different Google sheet instead of from tab to tab within the same Google sheet.

I have next to zero coding knowledge so unsure how I would edit it from here.

Comment: Welcome. If you didn't this yet please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets by the other hand, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have first get the ID of the target sheet from its url (the xxxx corresponds to the sheet ID:
    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/***xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx***/edit#gid=2116300997

to copy it for the following script:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var liness =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("your sheet id goes here");
//
//
var sheet = liness.getSheetByName("Fab")
var linevalues = sheet.getRange("A:W").getValues();
var lastrow=sheet.getLastRow();
```

Then you can open the new sheet and paste the values into any tab you want just like pasting in active sheet by using `setValues()`.

It will not copy formats and validation rules.

Then you have set values to blank by `setValues()` or `clearContent()` in the source sheet.